# Loop through collections

Tags: c#

I have two classes

```
class A
{
    public string something { get; set; }
    public IList<B> b= new List<B>();
}

class B
{
    public string else { get; set; }
    public string elseelse { get; set; }
}
```

I have populated an object of class A called obj. How can I loop through this object and print values. Do I have to use two foreach's like the one show here or is there a better way?

```
 foreach (var z  in obj)
            {
                // print z.something;
                foreach (var x in z.b)
                {
                    // print x.elseelse;
                }
            }
```

Comment: You never answered my question in the comment to Michaels answer. Judging from what you accepted as answer you don't have "an object of class A" at all, but actually a collection of objects of class A? Is that correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var qry = from z in obj
          from x in z.b
          select new { z, x };
foreach (var pair in qry)
{
     Console.WriteLine("{0}, {1}", pair.z.something, pair.x.elseelse);
}
```

or

```
var qry = from z in obj
          from x in z.b
          select new { z.zomething, x.elseelse };
foreach (var item in qry)
{
     Console.WriteLine("{0}, {1}", item.something, item.elseelse);
}
```

or project the string:

```
var qry = from z in obj
          from x in z.b
          select z.zomething + ", " + x.elseelse;
foreach (string s in qry)
{
     Console.WriteLine(s);
}
```

Comment: thanks marc..i also want to ask if there is anything wrong in using two foreach? is it old practice?

Comment: also how do I post the master record only once with all its details. Currently the master data is repeated

Comment: @ScG - nothing wrong with nested `foreach` *at all* - and it would fit your "master record once only" scenario neatly. That reqirement wasn't obvious from the question ;-p

Answer (score 2):

Your question is a little unclear to me. I'm assuming you have a collection of some object *A* and *A* has a collection property. If that's the case:

Your solution is the most straightforward way so I'd go with that.

You *could* use linq, but it won't really make this any faster or clearer. Something akin to this with [`SelectMany`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.selectmany.aspx), which flattens many IEnumerables into one:

```
foreach(var x in obj.SelectMany(z=>z.b)) { }
```

Comment: I want to print both z.something and x.elseelse

Comment: @ScG: So, is Michaels assumption correct, that you are not having an object of class A (as clearly stated in your question), but instead a collection of objects of class A?

Comment: @ScG--if you need to access both A and B, I'd suggest just going with what you have--it's really very clear. My solution, when adding in an anonymous type to KeyValuePair<> to keep track of A&B would make it difficult to read and no faster

Answer (score 2):

As there is only one collection, you don't need two loops. As your `obj` variable is not a collection, you can't even make a loop over it.

Just display the properties in your object and loop through the collection:

```
// print obj.something; 
foreach (var x in obj.b) {
  // print x.else; 
  // print x.elseelse; 
}
```

Comment: When I declare public IList<B> b= new List<B>(); in class A, what does it mean? Can you explain please. I just copied code from somewhere else

Comment: You have declared a field `b` with a type `IList<B>`.

Comment: @ScG: The answer for wRAR is correct but not complete. You have declared a field `b` of the type `IList<B>`, and initialised it to a new (empty) collection of type `List<B>`.

Comment: IMO, this is the most correct and simplest answer as there is no collection of class A and you would only need one loop

Answer (score 1):

No, just one foreach through obj.b:

```
foreach (var z in obj.b)
{
}
```